# Accessing Object properties, from HTML Select.

Tags: html, object, angularjs

**Scenario:**
I am trying to access a property (code) of a ng-Model object (myRide).

1. I've tried doing this by

   ```
   <select ng-model = "myRide" 
     ng-change = "getCode(myRide.code)">
   ```

   ...and at getCode,

   `alert(parameter) //which should be myRide.code.`
2. I've also tried to do this by

   ```
   <select ng-model = "myRide" 
     ng-change = getCode(myRide)
   ```

   (Note: 'myRide' is passed, not 'myRide.code') ...and at getCode,

   `alert(myRide.code).`

myRide does indeed contain a property called 'code', which is not undefined.

**Problem:** Both tries do not produce the wanted outcome.

---

**How can I make it display the property (code)?**

Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a2J6z/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/a2J6z/3/

```
var ngApp = angular.module('ngAppl',[]);

function aControlla($scope){

    $scope.myRide = "bus";

    $scope.getCode = function(car){
        alert(JSON.parse(car).code);
    }

    $scope.myGarage = [
        {Name: "Toyota 86", code:"1"},
        {Name: "Hyundai Genesis Coupe", code:"2"},
        {Name: "Nissan GTR", code:"3"},
        {Name: "Veyron", code:"4"}
    ];
};
```

And

```
<div ng-app="ngAppl">
    <div ng-controller="aControlla">

        <select ng-model="myRide" ng-change="getCode(myRide)">

            <option ng-repeat="car in myGarage">{{car}}</option> 
            <!--Note: value of myRide MUST be simply 'car' (not say, 'car.Code')-->

        </select>

        <br/> This shows that 'myRide' contains the property called 'Name', and importantly, 'code':<br/> {{myRide}}




    </div>
</div>
```

Basically I just had it alert what car was with myRide as the parameter, it showed the JSON string so I added the parse to get it to give me the code.  There may be a better way I'm an AngularJS noob so to speak.

Answer (score 2):

The better way to do this is to restructure the view. Instead of using ng-repeat on options inside of a select, use the ng-options directive. Then, you can bind the actual object to the model instead of just a JSON string, which is what your current fiddle is doing.

Your new select looks like

```
<select ng-options="car.Name for car in myGarage" ng-model="myRide" ng-change="getCode(myRide)"> 

</select>
```

Then in your controller

```
$scope.getCode = function(car){
    alert(car.code);
}
```

An updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/a2J6z/5/

Comment: The ng-options is indeed more convenient than ng-repeat. However I need to use ng-repeat for this instance, where I need to add in more options than those just from myGarage.